# Sending Email with a file attachment from React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, smtp

So I am using only the front-end and I need to have a contact form with the file attachments.

For this I decided to use emailjs and easy to set up everything just for the emails.
When I am adding a file and sending it in the email I am getting [object Object].

That's my font end code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef();

 const addFile = () => {
    inputFile.current.click();
  };

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" />

          <input
            name="image"
            type="file"
            onClick={addFile}
            ref={inputFile}
            value={file}
            onChange={(event: any) => setFile(event.target.value)}
          />

      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

So what I am doing wrong?
Maybe there are other 3rd party emailing service which have a better documentation for the react with a file attachments?

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to send an attachment in the mail. First you have to update your EmailJS account. The free account does not allow file attachments.
In non free accounts adding file attachments is possible in two ways – by passing the attachment content programmatically through the emailjs.send() call, or by allowing the user to upload a file. The latter is done by creating a form with a file input field, and sending the email via emailjs.sendForm(). To get started with either option first open your template editor - Attachments tab, and add an attachment.

Code Example

JS

```
function formSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', this);}
```

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="formSubmit()">
<label>Attach file:</label>
<input type="file" name="my_file"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```